# Sync column names of DataGrid and DataTable in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, columnheader

I have a DataGrid. When I change one of the DataGrid's column names, I want an event to arise so that the column name of the DataTable (the ItemSource of DataGrid) changes as well.

How can I sync the column names of the DataGrid and DataTable?

**EDIT**

I have datagrid like this with 6 column:

```
<wpfc4:RGrid x:Name="dgrid" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.CurrentDataTable}" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridRStyle}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></wpfc4:RGrid>
```

This RemoveSelectedColumn function :

```
 private void RemoveSelectedColumn()
    {
        DataGridColumn toRemove = this.Columns[_selectedColumnIndex];
        DataView view = this.ItemsSource as DataView;

        view.Table.Columns.Remove(toRemove.Header.ToString());  
        // deleting column from datatable.

        this.UpdateLayout();
        this.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

It's deleting from datatable but datagrid still has 6 column but deleted column has blank value. How I cna update datagrid so it shows only 4 column when i deleted 2 columns from datatable.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would try to reverse this so that any time you change the name of one of the columns in the `DataTable`, the `DataGrid` gets updated.

If you have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true` on your DataGrid, this should be quite straightforward:

1. Bind your DataGrid to your DataTable (using the `ItemsSource` property of the DataGrid).
2. Make sure the class that contains your DataGrid property implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then raise the `PropertyChanged` event any time a column name on your DataTable changes.

Comment: Instead of `this.Items.Refresh`, what happens if you try `this.ItemsSource = Model.CurrentDataTable`? Basically, I think you need to completely reset your `ItemsSource`, not just refresh the items. And I don't think you should need `UpdateLayout` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem what I did itemsource table first take in the temp variable and make itemsource  table object null , then remove the column and reassign the value to the itemsource table object...this works for me..

```
DataTable tempTable = ItemsourceDataTable;
ItemsourceDataTable= null;
tempTable.Columns.Remove("ColumnHeaderName");
ItemsourceDataTable= tempTable ;
```